# How can I make a meal list for each day?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to create a meal plan within a timeframe with a list of random food and drink items for each day. Ideally, I would like to have the setup as breakfast, lunch, and dinner. I am unsure how to put multiple for loops together for each section.

```
import random

def food_list1(food):
    food= random.choice(food_type)
    return("{}".format(food))

def food_list2(food2):
    food2 = random.choice(food_type2)
    return("{}".format(food2))
    
def drink_list(drink):
    drink = random.choice(drink_type)
    return("{}".format(drink))
    
food_type = ["hamburger wrapped in lettuce", "cheeseburger wrapped in lettuce", "tuna wrap", "salami in lettuce", "chicken noodle soup", "shrimp noodle soup", 
        "beef noodle soup", "pork noodle soup"]

food_type2 = ["chips", "celery sticks", "cesar salad", "chef salad", "carrot stick", "apple", "plum", "grapes"]

drink_type = ["apple juice", "milk", "peach juice", "orange juice", "powerade", "water"]


food = random.choice(food_type)
food2 = random.choice(food_type2)
drink = random.choice(drink_type)

from datetime import timedelta, date
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(0, int((end_date - start_date).days) + 1):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2023,7,6)
end_dt = date(2023,8,14)
for dt in daterange(start_dt,end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

for i in range(1):
    print(food_list1(food))

for i in range(1):
    print(food_list2(food2))

for i in range(1):
    print(drink_list(drink))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bring last three for loop inside the date range loop

```
import random

def food_list1(food):
    food= random.choice(food_type)
    return("{}".format(food))

def food_list2(food2):
    food2 = random.choice(food_type2)
    return("{}".format(food2))
    
def drink_list(drink):
    drink = random.choice(drink_type)
    return("{}".format(drink))
    
food_type = ["hamburger wrapped in lettuce", "cheeseburger wrapped in lettuce", "tuna wrap", "salami in lettuce", "chicken noodle soup", "shrimp noodle soup", 
        "beef noodle soup", "pork noodle soup"]

food_type2 = ["chips", "celery sticks", "cesar salad", "chef salad", "carrot stick", "apple", "plum", "grapes"]

drink_type = ["apple juice", "milk", "peach juice", "orange juice", "powerade", "water"]


food = random.choice(food_type)
food2 = random.choice(food_type2)
drink = random.choice(drink_type)

from datetime import timedelta, date
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(0, int((end_date - start_date).days) + 1):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2023,7,6)
end_dt = date(2023,8,14)
for dt in daterange(start_dt,end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    for i in range(1):
        print(food_list1(food))
    
    for i in range(1):
        print(food_list2(food2))
    
    for i in range(1):
        print(drink_list(drink))
    print()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
for dt in daterange(start_dt,end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Each iteration of this loop represents one day. For each day, you want to pick two random food items and a beverage:

```
for dt in daterange(start_dt,end_dt):
    date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    food_1 = random.choice(food_type)
    food_2 = random.choice(food_type2)
    drink = random.choice(drink_type)

    print(f"Meal plan for {date}:")
    print(f"{food_1} with {food_2} and {drink}")
```

Your `food`, `food2`, `drink` variables and `food_list1`, `food_list2` and `drink_list` functions aren't really doing anything useful. You can remove them.